# Multi-Column TreeView for Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, grid, treeview, multiple-columns, firemonkey

Recently I came across a component called Virtual Treeview but it only works for VCL applications.

My problem is: I'm developing an application using Firemonkey.

Is there a free component that supports multiple columns on a treeview or will I need to create my own?

I'm using Delphi XE7.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I just started to make a frame for it.

It's gonna be a StringGrid with 1 fixed column that has a TreeView inside it.

May post details when it's done.